# Plotly in R is showing my X axis with "M" for Millions - how do I show the Real Number

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

My x-axis is showing numbers with an "M". Any ideas on how to remove this? I have tried messing with the tick settings and it does not work.

[image: Graph X-Axis using "M" (e.g. 120M) instead of actual value]

Answer (score 0):

Try `tickformat = ".0f"`:

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(
  type = "scatter",
  x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12) * 1e9, 
  y = c(0.18, 0.38, 0.56, 0.46, 0.59, 0.4, 0.78, 0.77, 0.74, 0.42, 0.45, 0.39), 
  mode = "markers+lines") 

fig %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(
      tickformat = ".0f"
    )
  )
```

You can try the possibilities [here](http://bl.ocks.org/zanarmstrong/05c1e95bf7aa16c4768e). Oddly, `tickformat = ""` does not give the unformatted number.